# Running ffmpeg on command line not working

Tags: python, ffmpeg, os.system

I would like to run a command over command line in Python. When I open cmd and issue the following command it works:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i C:\test\test.txt -c copy C:\test\out.MP4
```

Now I try to run it in Python in the following way:

```
from subprocess import check_call
concat_list = "C:\\test\\test.txt"
out_file = "C:\\test\\out.MP4"
check_call(["ffmpeg", "-f", "concat", "-safe", "0", "-i", concat_list, "-c", "copy", out_file])
```

When I do this I get the error "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified".

What is my mistake?

The full error message is:

```
    'ffmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/trunk/python/xxx/src/videos/processVideo.py", line 48, in <module>
        check_call(["ffmpeg", "-f", "concat", "-safe", "0", "-i", concat_list, "-c", "copy", out_file])
      File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_call
        retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 317, in call
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
      File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 769, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1172, in _execute_child
        startupinfo)
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: maybe you have to use `"C:\\full\\path\\to\\ffmpeg.exe"`

Comment: you forgot `"` in `concat_list = "C:\\test\\test.txt"` and `out_file = "C:\\test\\out.MP4"`

Comment: @furas I have added the full error message. I have used the ". Just forgot it in my post. Using the full path to ffmpeg does not work because there is white space in the in some folder name in the path. But ffmpeg is in path so should be recognized.

Comment: Does it work in shell when you activate your conda env?

Comment: @ReutSharabani How can I do that?

Comment: I know that I used to do `conda activate` or `conda activate envname`, but you're on windows so it could be different.

Comment: It seems that it does not find ffmpeg somehow. Althought when I use "ffmpeg" in command line it works (it is in PATH). I also tried to use "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\ffmpeg-4.1.3-win64-static\bin\fffmpeg.exe" which does not work although this directory exists.

Comment: So it doesn't work on conda specifically? Can you check if conda changes your path?

Comment: @Reut How can I check if conda changes the path? By the way in cmd "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\ffmpeg-4.1.3-win64-static\bin\fffmpeg.exe" is also not working. Don't know why.

Comment: you have an extra `f` in the file name :)

Comment: @ReutSharabani Oh damn, now everything works. Thanks.